# Server side misses notifications due to an outage when client buy subscriptions - App Store Server Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, subscription, storekit, in-app-subscription

I'm using App Store Server Notifications V2

I'm implementing the subscription purchasing function in our app on iOS, everything seems to be fine, but I still have an issue that needs to be resolved, which is the case when the user purchases a subscription but the server side of the application If we crash, for example, how can I restore premium functionality for users?

In Apple's documentation, there are instructions that say `you can recover missed notifications by calling "Get Notification History"` but if I have solved this case from the **Get Notification History** API that Apple provides, how can I check if the subscription has been resolved.

And how to notify Apple that the subscription has been processed and remove it from the **Get Notification History** API?

Or is there any other better way to handle it? Please help me.

I'm newbiew, thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

1. Queue notifications (Redis, RabbitMQ) to avoid loss during crashes.
2. Regularly retrieve missed notifications (Get Notification History).
3. Verify subscriptions (server-side or local storage if possible).
4. Handle different notifications (new, renewal, cancel/refund).
5. Optionally remove processed notifications (EndSession, use caution).
6. Error handling, logging, and thorough testing are crucial.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you tell me how to verify on the server side? (Verify subscriptions (server-side or local storage if possible)). I couldn't find it in Apple's documentation, because with my case, i'm finishTransaction from App before server side crash

Comment: You can review this link [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_notification_history)